# How iterate specific list's property

Tags: javascript, list, properties, increment

Im new on JS and i already push all content from [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) on my arraylist `MyList` but i wanted to get all `title` property to push on my `titleList`

[image]

I don't know if i need to use incrementation get all title, so i found this exemple which seems logical to me :

```
...
const MyList = []
MyList.push(json_response)

const titleList = []

Object.keys(MyList).forEach(key => {
   console.log(key, obj[title]);
   titleList.push([title])
 });
```

and i found this:

```
 ReferenceError: Cannot access 'title' before initialization
    at /Users/mac/Desktop/My_test/index.js:55:28
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/mac/Desktop/My_test/index.js:42:33
```

Comment: Where do you think you have defined `title`?

Comment: @Scott-Hunter i add a image to explain this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

title is not defined at this point provided json_response has data try this...

```
const MyList    = []
const titleList = []

MyList.push(json_response)

MyList.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item);
  titleList.push(item.title)
});
```